# Comparing ShapeFile Data in C#

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, c#, comparison

I have made a List containing all the original data (.shp files), and I have another List containing the modified data. I basically want to check all the modified file data against the original... So here lies the problem, I next a loop within a loop to check if the original exists within the modified List... and it always seems to find a match? Is my approach right?

This is the sample code I have for PointZ type shapes

```
 foreach (PointZ origrecord in origPointZList)
        {
            Boolean foundIt = false;

            foreach (PointZ modrecord in origPointZList)
            {
                if ((origrecord.X == modrecord.X)
                    && (origrecord.Y == modrecord.Y)
                    && (origrecord.Z == modrecord.Z)
                    && (origrecord.M == modrecord.M))
                {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                    foundIt = false;
                }

            }
            if (!foundIt)
            {
                result += "Record not found";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your foreach loops iterate the same list!

Comment: I think I changed it to that for testing... if not... wow, can't believe I wouldn't have noticed that.

Comment: Actually that was it... I think I need more coffee, thank you!